# Circumventing a router - sort of

Tags: networking, router

I am trying to attach an IP camera to a router at a clients premises. the network is using a static IP address as they host their own web site.

When I attach the camera I cannot access the rtsp feed.

The ip camera is on a static IP address (factory default). It is 192.168.100.100. Which is a different subnet to the dhcp server at 192.168.1.1..

I contacted their admin guy who is in Spain and he said it all needs replacing and i will not be able to get the ip camera working. I think he wants to charge the client (As he is a consultant) more money for not much work.

I included that last paragraph because I know people will quite rightly ask me to contact the network admin guy.

Now, all this is not my strongest field. I am guessing what to do which is never good.

I will be visiting the client this afternoon.

I was going to propose setting the default of the ip camera to DHCP settings. I am hoping that the rtsp port 554 is open. I do not know what to do if it is not or where I can open it from within the router settings.

The other option I was considering is to use a separate hub/router. I attach the ip camera and a standalone PC to it. All I would need then is an internet connection. Is it feasible to use wireless from main router to this 'sub-router' to get this working?

the current router is a tp-link router.

Any advice on whether my 2 suggested options would work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would be a terrible idea to expose the camera to the public intrernet. Instead determine whether any remote access systems are already available (VPN, SSH, etc) and if so, use them to connect to the lan and access the camera as though you were local.

Comment: you will have to change the camera's IP address to be on the lan subnet. adding an interior router will address the IP subnet issue, but will likely exacerbate the port access issue.

Comment: Hi Frank. thank so so much for your time.  Just to clarify things here. The RTSP feed will only be available from within the local network. The internet access is just so I can upload saved motion/images/footage to my server. It seems the easiest option you suggest is to change the subnet of the IP camera. The ONLY issue I got with this is that if I have a client who lives far away from me and if the IP cameras needs a hard reset then the IP camera will revert back to that static IP address.  When means support for it as I would have to change it back to a dhcp setting.